# Type checking of std::map of keys and/or values of type boost::any?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

I am writing helper functions which converts `DBus` properties values to std types. For that, to convert few type, i need to create a `std::map`. The map will represent `DICT` type in `DBus`. The DICT type in `DBUS` can have any type as a key and any type as it's value. Now, I need to convert it to `std::map`. I am thinking of using `std::map<boost::any, boost::any>` for `DICT` type of `DBUS`. However, I have to check the type after converting all the types of `DBUS` to std types. But it looks like i can't do it as the program below fails (obviously):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, boost::any> m;
    boost::any key = 2;
    boost::any value = std::string("Hello");

    m.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("Key"), value));

    if (typeid(m) == typeid(std::map<std::string, std::string>))
        std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am looking for better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `boost::any` as an associative container key is rather inconvenient. For ordered containers it must support `operator<`, for unordered - `operator==` and `std::hash` (or a hash of your choice). You would need to implement this functionality yourself but `boost::any` does not provide a convenient way to query the type of the stored value.

An ideal choice is probably `boost::variant` for both key and values, since [DBUS has a limited number of types](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#idm399): integers, double, string; dictionaries and variants can be modelled with recursive [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive).

Implementing the required operators for `boost::variant` is straightforward: compare the value type first and, if they match, the value itself.